# How to display content of a marker not in infowindow but in a div outside map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've put a marker on a place on map and centered my map on this point while loading. i want to display this marker's content in a div outside map, without clicking on page or any other action! sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Please show the code that you have? It's very difficult to understand your goal.

Comment: When you click on a marked point in google map, it shows some details about it outside the map and in a infoWindow above that point.
I've put a marker on myLatlang, using this code, and i want to show it's details outside the map. but in my application, i do not have a mouse to click, so i want this details aboute the marked point, while map is loading, but i do not know how to do that!

     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
        });
        marker.setMap(map);

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
document.getElementById('YourDivId').innerHTML = 'What you want to show.';
```

To show the information in a div. If you want to show it when the last marker is placed on the map, then you can use an array of markers, reach the last one and use the marker's information with innerHTML.

Comment: Mm! actually, my problem is how to get the infoWindow details, not how to show it!

Comment: What kind of details? If you want information about the place where infoWindow is placed, you need to consult the route or Geocode the place...infoWindows are used to show information instead of get them.